# How to show a message in the Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying Google Maps JavaScript API v2. I want to show a message in the map. No matter how I drag or zoom the map, the message will keep in the same place. How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI: Google Maps JS API v2 is deprecated. Use V3.

Comment: @Māris Thanks. I know. The code base uses v2. And I don't plan to change it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this right,why don't you make a div that changes location using the animation of jquery?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did so.
I think it's interesting to see whether it's possible to do it in the Google Maps. :)